# Less-than operator failing in a PHP string

Tags: php, string

```
var_dump('<a>')
// or
var_dump("<a>")
// or
var_dump("\x3Ca>")

// all result in
string(3) ""
```

What is going on? Only putting a space after the less-than sign works for me.

PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<a>` is probably getting rendered as an empty tag in the browser - try viewing the page source

Comment: It is. Add htmlspecialchars() to get a printable version.

Comment: Or render as plain text rather than HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I believe var_dump takes an expression, not a string. So:

```
<?php

$a = "<a>";
var_dump($a); 

?>
```

Should work.

Comment: No, var_dump() can also handle plain string.